# Microsoft graph : UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: PolyFillNotAvailable: Library cannot function without fetch. So, please provide polyfill for it

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Microsoft graph throws the below exception when initializing the client using the access token

[image]

the access token was generated just before initializing the client & also the  same token works in post-man

what is that I'm doing wrong?

code

```
let graphClient = graph.Client.init({
        // Use the provided access token to authenticate
        // requests
        authProvider: (done) => {
            done(null, accessToken);
        }
    });
```

Post-man response

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Quoting the [install guide](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client#installation):

*import @microsoft/microsoft-graph-client into your module and also you will need polyfills for fetch like isomorphic-fetch.*

Here is what you need to do.

```
npm install isomorphic-fetch
import "isomorphic-fetch"; OR require('isomorphic-fetch');
```